# Import Customer Data & Password Programmatically Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.2-p1

I want to import Customer Data & Password programmatically using a custom script in Magento 2. Anyone did the same, please specify.
Thanks in advance.

Rashi

Answer (score 0):

> **Try Below Code:**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Import;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor;

class ImportData extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $customer;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $customerRegistry;
    protected $dataProcessor;
    protected $_customerRepository;
    protected $_mathRandom;
    protected $_accountmanagement;
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Math\Random $mathRandom,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement $accountmanagement,
        DataObjectProcessor $dataProcessor,
        CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->dataProcessor = $dataProcessor;
        $this->_accountmanagement = $accountmanagement;
        $this->_customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_mathRandom = $mathRandom;
        $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->senderResolver = $senderResolver ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SenderResolverInterface::class);
    }
    public function execute()
    {

        $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue(); // customer data
        $postData['storeviews'] = 0; // Website ID
        $postData['email_template'] = "customer_password_forgot_email_template";// add your email template name
        $createdCustomer = $this->createCustomer($postData, $postData['storeviews'], $postData['email_template']);

        ..................................................
        ..................................................
        ..................................................

    }

    public function createCustomer($data, $websiteId, $emailTemplate, $pharmacistNumber = 0)
    {
        $count = 0;
        $checkCustomer = $this->customer->create()->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($data[0]);
        if (!$checkCustomer->hasData()) {
            try {
                $createCustomer = $this->customer->create();
                $createCustomer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
                $createCustomer->setEmail($data[0]); // customer email
                $createCustomer->setFirstname($data[1]); // customer First name
                $createCustomer->setLastname($data[2]); // customer Last name
                $createCustomer->setGroupId($data[3]); // Customer group Name

                $createCustomer->save();

                /* Send Email TO Customer */
                $emailSendStatus = $this->sendEmailToCustomer($createCustomer, $emailTemplate, $data['referer_url']);
                $count = 1;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $msg =  "Something went wrong when creating customer.";
                $this->_messageManager->addError(__($msg));
            }
        } else {
            $msg = 'Customer Already Created.';
            $this->_messageManager->addError(__($msg));
        }
        return $count;
    }

    public function getStoreId($websiteId)
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getWebsite($websiteId)->getDefaultStore()->getId();
    }

    public function getStoreName($websiteId)
    {
        return $this->storeManager->getWebsite($websiteId)->getDefaultStore()->getName();
    }

    public function sendEmailToCustomer($customer, $emailTemplate)
    {

        $storeId = $this->getStoreId($customer->getWebsiteId());
        $customerEmailData = $this->getFullCustomerObject($customer);
        $templateParams = [];
        $templateParams['customer'] = $customerEmailData;
        $templateParams['store'] = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId);

        $sender = \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification::XML_PATH_FORGOT_EMAIL_IDENTITY;

        $from = $this->senderResolver->resolve(
            $this->scopeConfig->getValue($sender, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId),
            $storeId
        );

        $customerName = $customer->getFirstname() . " " . $customer->getLastname();

        try {
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($emailTemplate)
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $storeId])
                ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
                ->setFrom($from)
                ->addTo($customer->getEmail(), $customerName)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->logger->info($customer->getEmail() . ' : Email Send Successfully.');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($customer->getEmail() . ' : Something went wrong when sending email');
        }
    }

    public function getFullCustomerObject($customer)
    {
        $mergedCustomerData = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customer->getId());
        $customerData = $this->dataProcessor
            ->buildOutputDataArray($customer, CustomerInterface::class);
        $mergedCustomerData->addData($customerData);
        $customerName = $customer->getFirstname() . " " . $customer->getLastname();
        $mergedCustomerData->setData('name', $customerName);
        $tokenVal = $this->getToken($customer->getEmail(), $customer->getWebsiteId());
        $mergedCustomerData->setData('rp_token', $tokenVal);
        return $mergedCustomerData;
    }

    public function getToken($email, $websiteId)
    {
        $customer = $this->_customerRepository->get($email, $websiteId);
        $newPasswordToken = $this->_mathRandom->getUniqueHash();
        $this->_accountmanagement->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($customer, $newPasswordToken);
        return $newPasswordToken;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, @Msquare thanks. Allow me sometime to review this solution

Comment: @RashiGoyal have you checked code ?